# .join() with a timeout still waits for the daemon thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join), particularly this part:

> This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is
>   called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception
>   – **or until the optional timeout occurs**.

I gather that when the `timeout` is not `None`, the calling thread is supposed to wait for the daemon, that amount of time before exiting (if other non-daemon threads finished their work). Although, this example proves differently, thus my understanding is incorrect:

```
import threading
import time
import logging


def daemon():
    logging.debug('Starting')
    time.sleep(10)
    logging.debug('Exiting')


def non_daemon():
    logging.debug('Starting')
    logging.debug('Exiting')


logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
)

d = threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=daemon, daemon=True)

t = threading.Thread(name='non-daemon', target=non_daemon)

d.start()

t.start()

d.join(0.3)
print('d.isAlive()', d.isAlive())
t.join()
```

Can someone please explain to me, why the calling thread (Main Thread) does not exit after waiting for the daemon thread for `0.3` seconds? But rather waits for the full `10` seconds? Clearly I do not understand the meaning of the timeout argument. All the explanations I found on the Internet are the same and basically say this:

> It is also possible to pass a float value representing the number of
>   seconds to wait for the thread to become inactive. If the thread does
>   not complete within the timeout period, join() returns anyway.

, which makes little sense to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The timeout argument means just what it says.  `d.join(0.3)` will return after thread `d` exits, or after 0.3 seconds, whichever comes first.  If it's important for the caller to do something different depending on whether `d` still is running, then it will have to call  `d.is_alive()` to find out which is the case.

Dealing with the obvious race condition there is *your* problem.

> Can someone please explain to me, why the calling thread (Main Thread)...waits for the full 10 seconds?

That's not what happened when I ran your program in Python 3.5.4. It terminated for me after less than one second, and it never printed `(daemon    ) Exiting`.  Are you sure that the code you posted is the same as the code that you are running?

If so, what version of Python are you using to run it?